# Filter cells in pandas dataframe with arrays in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

You can see my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b1c7.jpg).

How can I filter this column (`childGTalleles`) if I have there cells like: [0, 0], [0, 1], or similar?

I have three columns `(fatherGTalleles, motherGTalleles and childGTalleles)` and I was trying something like `newdff = newdf[(newdf.childGTalleles == "[0, 0]")]` but it's not working (returns zero rows).

I'd like also to filter these columns by something like that:

```
fatherGTalleles == [0, 0] & motherGTalleles == [0, 1] & childGTalleles == [0, 1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always much better to share code itself, instead of sharing ss, so that developers can copy your code for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that data type of `childGTalleles` numpy array. You have to take double quotes from your code and use `np.array_equal`:

```py
newdff = newdf[np.array_equal(newdf.childGTalleles, [0, 0])]
```

For your second question, you can try this:

```py
filtered_df = df[np.array_equal(newdf.fatherherGTalleles, [0, 0]) &&
                 np.array_equal(newdf.motherGTalleles, [0, 0]) &&
                 np.array_equal(newdf.childGTalleles, [0, 0])]
```

Comment: `pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False`

Comment: `newdf[newdf['childGTalleles'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x,[0,0]))]` - try this one. I agree, this looks messy, but I could come up with this

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Maybe this should work also for second question.

Comment: @Szymon, you are welcome. Probably it will work, but I guess there is much better solution

Comment: If someone needed answer:
filtered_df = df[newdf['fatherGTalleles'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x,[0,0])) &
                 newdf['motherGTalleles'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x,[0,0])) &
                 newdf['childGTalleles'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x,[1,1]))]